# unresolved supertypes: java.lang.Record in android flutter while importing Jar file

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am trying to add some jar files to my flutter app.but when I am building the app , it gives unresolved supertypes : java.lang.Record.

Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:

> Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make
> sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>
> unresolved supertypes: java.lang.Record

my project build.gradle

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.9.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

dependencies {
}
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle is

```
 plugins {
        id "com.android.application"
        id "kotlin-android"
        id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
        id "com.google.protobuf"
    
    }
    
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
        localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
            localProperties.load(reader)
        }
    }
    
    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
        flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }
    
    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
        flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }
    
    android {
        namespace "com.example.jar"
        compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        }
    
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        }
    
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            main {
                java {
                    exclude 'com.guardtime.front.FrontServiceConfiguration.java'
                }
            }
        }
    
        defaultConfig {
            // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
            applicationId "com.example.jar"
            // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
            // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
            minSdkVersion 26
    
            targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
            versionName flutterVersionName
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
    }
    
    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }
    
    dependencies {
        
        //implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        implementation files('libs/DEMO-SNAPSHOT.jar')
   
    
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.58.0'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.58.0'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.58.0'
        implementation 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-kotlin:1.3.1'
        implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:1.3.1'
        implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:3.24.3'
        
    
    }
```

tried different ways like changing the jdk versions , but failed.